# Select filename using FileDialog

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to get a fullpath and filename using the file dialog from MS Access VBA.

What I am trying to do is to open the file Dialog on button click by calling this function. This function should return the fullpath and filename that was selected from the filedialog.

I commented the loop part because I only want to select single file.

This function is returning an error `Error: 0` after I select a file

So far this is my code.

Anyone can figure out what's wrong?

Thanks

```
Public Function SelectTheFile() As String

On Error GoTo SelectTheFile_ErrorHandler

        Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
        Dim varFile As Variant

        Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

        With fDialog

            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            .Title = "Please select one file"

            If .Show = True Then
                'For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
                   'SelectTheFile = varFile
                   'Debug.Print SelectTheFile
                'Next
                SelectTheFile = .SelectedItems(1)
                Debug.Print SelectTheFile
            Else
                Debug.Print "Cancel"
            End If
        End With

SelectTheFile_ErrorHandler:
    Set fd = Nothing
    MsgBox "Error " & Err & ": " & Error(Err)

End Function
```

Comment: You're simply missing `Exit Function` before `SelectTheFile_ErrorHandler:` so the code keeps running to the end. And I don't think you need `Set fd = Nothing`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code always reach the `SelectTheFile_ErrorHandler:` section whatever the file dialog result

you must exit the function before that section

```
   Public Function SelectTheFile() As String

    On Error GoTo SelectTheFile_ErrorHandler

            Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
            Dim varFile As Variant

            Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

            With fDialog

                .AllowMultiSelect = False
                .Title = "Please select one file"

                If .Show = True Then
                    'For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
                       'SelectTheFile = varFile
                       'Debug.Print SelectTheFile
                    'Next
                    SelectTheFile = .SelectedItems(1)
                    Debug.Print SelectTheFile
                Else
                    Debug.Print "Cancel"
                End If
            End With

            Exit Function '<==== exit here, otherwise code goes on to following section 

    SelectTheFile_ErrorHandler:
        Set fDialog = Nothing
        MsgBox "Error " & Err & ": " & Error(Err)

    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Try just using this:

```
Application.GetOpenFilename
```

That works for me and saves the full file path without actually opening the file. Much simpler unless I am missing what you're trying to do. Read more here in the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834966.aspx

Comment: This is really helpful. I would say this also solves my problem but I have decided to award the answer to the next answer because he does explain why I am getting the error and solve the problem at the same time. but I have to admit, if I know this method before hand, I should have used this instead of what I have now. Thanks a lot!