# Powerpoint FileDialog box issues (VBA)

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In a small Powerpoint application I'm coding I use the .FileDialog method to enable the user to select the target file for the app. Everything works fine, except if the user wants to cancel the dialog by either clicking the cancel button or the X in the upper RH corner, an error is generated and execution fails.

So, what are the PowerPoint error traps if the user wants to cancel? I tried using Excel VBA code ('On Error', vbCancel, and If statements) to trap the error with no luck.

Any suggestions?

```
Sub ShowFileDialog()

Dim dlgOpen As FileDialog

Set dlgOpen = Application.FileDialog(Type:=msoFileDialogOpen)

With dlgOpen
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Show

[meta code] If selection = "" then exit sub
or
if vbCancel = True then exit sub

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: *an error is generated* is a useless problem description unless you tell us what specific error occurs. What error message are you getting? If the user presses Cancel, `vbCancel` is returned, and there is no error message unless you're displaying one yourself. Also, there are many existing questions here about using FileDialog in VBA; whether they're tagged PowerPoint or not is irrelevant, as VBA works the same in all Office apps. Search this site for `[vba] FileDialog`, where you can easily find examples [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35626791/62576)

Comment: see my comment in the other response. The apparent issue is that using the '.Show' method directly assumed a file had to be selected (which generated Run Time Error 5: "Invalid Procedure Call Argument" if I tried to cancel the action). Using the If statement solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show returns a value.

```
Sub ShowFileDialog()
Dim dlgOpen As FileDialog`

Set dlgOpen = Application.FileDialog(Type:=msoFileDialogOpen)

With dlgOpen
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    If .Show Then
       Dim I As Integer
       For I = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
          Debug.Print .SelectedItems(I)
       Next
    Else
       Debug.Print "User cancelled"
    End If
 End With

End Sub
```

Comment: using the 'If .Show ...'  construct solved the problem